# No rights on page-module level

Tags: typo3, rights, templavoila, rights-management

I encounter a strange error. On page-module level i´m not allowed to create new page elements. If i do the same via the list-module page-elements are created and i can edit them (even in the page-module).

Also, if i created a flexible content element - e.g. columns - (via the list module) i CAN create new elements in the flexible content element, even in page module.

New elements are always on TOP of the page, meaning the first entry, and i can´t drag and drop them. Well, i can, but changes do not come in effect. To sort the elements I have to edit the page properties, and sort `content`.

The user has every right(!) given by the user settings, and it is TYPO3 4.7.4

Does anyone know where i have to look for a solution? Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**

This error appears in the log:

`Attempt to insert record on page '[root-level]' (0) where this table, tt_content, is not allowed (msg#1.1.11)`

Again: Creating Elements IS working via the `List-Module`.

Comment: Please do not ask many questions at once. It seems that you use `TemplaVoila`. Please ask questions related to non-core feature in the extension mailing-list or make it clear that you have a problem with an extension. Last, but not least, what is the error message if you try to create a new page in the page module? BTW you can just drag new pages from the pagetree toolbar into the pagetree (click on the first icon above the pagetree).

Comment: Did i ask many questions? `Does anyone know where I have to look...` Creating pages is ok - no problems here - creating new content elements (while the page-module is active) is not working -> `You do not have sufficient rights to perform this change.` But, anyway: Thanks for the little drag-and-drop tip, haven´t ever seen this option!

Comment: Yes I use `TemplaVoila` - but I´m not sure if this problem is extension-related.

Comment: Did you check your PHP error log (or backend log (below admin tools). Did you test whether is works if you turn the user into an admin user?

Comment: Also, there might be `TSconfig` or `UserTS` options set which prevent saving the elements.

Comment: The following error is found in the log: `Attempt to insert record on page '[root-level]' (0) where this table, tt_content, is not allowed (msg#1.1.11)`

Comment: User has been given admin rights, as far as i can see, there are no special TSconfig settings. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

This error is causen because the field `t3ver_swapmode` in the `page` table was removed since TYPO3 4.7 (Maybe in combination with TemplaVoila).

I dont know whats exactly going on here (didnt had the time to find that out), but the solution is of cource simple. I uploaded my fix to the TYPO repository under the key `swapmodefix` http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/swapmodefix

The extension appears in a couple of hours, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a page inside the pagetree first. You may not create content elements on the root page.

It might be that the selection is lost, but still visibel. Just click the page again.